# React - using doc ready js file for jquery?

Tags: reactjs

I'm a react noobie and trying to do all my element manipulation inside my components (willMount, didMount handlers, etc.) but I am sooooooo used to throwing everything into a doc ready function in a main.js file.

Having said that, what is the disadvantage of leaning on a main.js file for element manipulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React is a [Virtual DOM](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/glossary.html) and by manually editing the DOM you are skipping the most powerful feature of React.
Also, by not using the props and the states you are not really benefits from it.

If you like to gain the DOM element reference you can do it by using [Refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html) but other then that I'll personally won't recommend that.